# Disable Schema suggestions in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I like the suggestions when I'm writing HTML and CSS but this is a very annoying thing when I'm writing front matter in a Jekyll page. Is there a way to disable suggestions for anything relating to schema.

[image: example of error]

Answer (score 0):

It was the liquid plugin I was using, oh the irony.